# Magento 2.1.4 add Category Image into Product Image Slider?

Tags: magento-2.1, product, category, product-images

I'm new to Magento and I'm using **2.1.4** . I want to add **Category image** into the **Product Image Slider** top Corner. I search in **Magento forum** and I can't find it any where. All the example are for **early magento editions**.

If any one can help, it would be GREAT.

Comment: Can u please give a screenshot where are you want to add this?

Comment: please share the block and template  code

Comment: Please view in here http://tinypic.com/r/331qa38/9